# How to achieve a "one size fits all" Ubuntu USB which doesn't have many hardware issues on different computers

Tags: usb, hardware, crossplatform

I've successfully fully installed Ubuntu onto a USB which can boot on my Macbook Air and Windows PC (and hopefully anywhere else). I'm putting Ubuntu on this USB so I can use it anywhere, on anybody's computer - my portable work station. It could be old and crappy, or new and beefy.

The problems now are to do with hardware (I assume) when I use the installed Ubuntu on a computer other than that which I installed it on.

There are graphical glitches, serious display bugs, random errors (like it freezing up when trying to search for an application (Terminal) to open), and more. This is just on one computer. Other computers will have different problems, it'll go on and on. It's not plausible to try and fix each individual problem.

I realise the installation would've configured some stuff for the hardware and system that was being used at the time. These problems are cramping my style.

Is a **more** hardware agnostic installation possible? (I realise truly hardware agnostic is NOT possible, but do you know any basic improvements?)

I'm fine with limiting/simplifying the graphics/installation and such - I just want it to operate relatively smoothly in most places.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Try downloading the GNOME desktop environment, it's clean, and runs lighter than Unity.

Comment: Firstly, I would use a DE which is morge clean, like cremefraiche says. Maybe lubuntu would be my choice.
Then you should not install the proprietary drivers for nvidia/ATI. Now the only problem you will have, is support of the newest display cards. The rest should work.

Comment: How do I not install the drivers? AFAIK, I never elected to install them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't install any proprietary drivers and are using 32 bit, your Ubuntu USB should boot almost any computer that is up to minimum spec, PAE, 512MB RAM, 700 MHz processor, etc.

There are versions you can run if you are planning on using older computers, say without PAE, or enough RAM.

Comment: Thanks Cameron, I'm just wondering if there's any automatic installation of proprietary drivers when you install Ubuntu normally, and if so, how I can avoid them? Does it detect your hardware and install stuff for it? Because I never manually installed anything - I didn't use the OS at all before trying to jump from one computer to another. I'll double check that it's not a 32/64 bit problem but I used it on a new-ish computer and it had some serious problems, so I'd be surprised if that was it.

Comment: 2unco: I have been using both Persistent and Full install flash drives for many years now and the only time I have had a problem using them on multiple machines is after intentionally installing proprietary drivers, (ie Nvidia), or when the host machine was old and crappy, (ie no PAE, not enough RAM, obsolete video card, slow processor, etc). Nowadays even Puppy Linux requires a Gig of RAM. There can be other problems with "one size fits all" such as trying to use 32 bit Ubuntu with UEFI or secure boot.

Comment: Fair enough @C.S.Cameron, I hope it's just a 64/32 bit issue then. Which flavour has been working for you? The comments to the question recommend Gnome or other light versions. I'd personally like to stay as close to the... "default" Ubuntu as I can, but the one downloaded straight off the site is that which was causing me problems. Also, did you use the +mac version? I had to do that so I can run it on my Macbook Air and PC.